# How to detect is the page is running on web app?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

How to detect is the page is running on a web app like 'Add to Home Screen' feature on browsers? Tried searching, but no useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Fixed:

in `manifest.json`, added `?mode=webapp` in `start-url`.

Comment: that's a naive way of doing it - a less naive way, `window.navigator.standalone || document.referrer.includes("android-app://") ||
 window.matchMedia("(display-mode: standalone)").matches` - this has worked for me for years